# Using the result of TikZ foreach evaluate

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I was trying to display the value of an evaluated variable in a TikZ foreach loop on a very basic example (tweaked from https://tikz.dev/pgffor#pgf./pgf/foreach/evaluate), but somehow it fails. See MWE below. I learned that \shade is a reserved word, but then why is it used (just fine) in the official example?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \shade using \x*10] in {0,1,...,10} {
        \node [fill=red!\shade!yellow, minimum size=0.65cm] at (\x,0) {\shade};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: isn't `\shade` is a reserved word with TikZ ?

Comment: probably not worth a proper answer so @administrators, feel free to delete mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\shade` is a reserved word with TikZ. Rename it `\shadenumber` ?

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \shadenumber using \x*10] in {0,1,...,10} {
        \node [fill=red!\shadenumber!yellow, minimum size=0.65cm] at (\x,0) {\shadenumber} ;
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense, but then why would they redefine a reserved keyword in an example? https://tikz.dev/pgffor#pgf./pgf/foreach/evaluate

Comment: @Cryme ummm... interesting. You should amend your question with that pointed out.

Comment: Also it seems strange to me that it works just fine in the color specification but not as a node label.

Comment: `\x` is also reserved, but it is all about scope - even this will work: `\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \fill [evaluate=\fill as \draw using \fill*10] in {0,1,...,10}
\node [fill=red!\draw!yellow, minimum size=0.65cm] at (\fill,0) {1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: That is absolutely insane.